# How to retrieve all td where the id begin by td_ in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I need your help :) !

I have a page where there are a lot of  tags and I have to retrieve in an array all id who begin by td_

I can not use the jQuery framework... Else there will be more easy...

Do you how I can do it ?

Comment: In “pure” JS, get all TD elements using getElementsByTagName, loop over those, and check their id with indexOf - and if it checks out, put them into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the querySelector:

```
elementList = document.querySelectorAll('td[id^=td_]');
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fzW4h/)

```
var nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=td_]'); // or if only TDs are tergated use: 'td[id^=td_]' instead   {thx Derek}
var arr = []; // Will hold the array of Node's
for (var i = 0, ll = nodeList.length; i < ll; arr.push(nodeList[i++]));
```

Comment: Please consider to comment on downvote...

Comment: It is extremely inefficient to search for attribute only, as it forces JS to search all attributes of every element on the page; use `'td[id^="td_"]'` instead.  And what's the point of `arr` and the `for` loop when `nodeList` is already an array?

Comment: Please give us a moment to type the comment on the downvote! (Downvote removed and comment amended, as the reason for the downvote was the malformed selector, which you've fixed.)

Comment: @DerekHenderson thx for the input. Typo fixed. OP stated: << there are a lot of tags and I have to retrieve in an array all id who begin by td_ >>  So i suppose there are not only TDs

Comment: True, but then his title also makes clear that he is targeting TDs. ;)

Comment: @DerekHenderson and OP still stated he wants array, querySelectorAll returns a prototype nodeList. But i'm quite sure OP doesn't really know what he was expecting for ;)

Comment: I didn't realise that about `querySelectorAll`. I assumed it returned an array. Thank you for that clarification.