# Call element by id in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a repeater and have a label with an icon inside it.

```
 <strong><i id="iconProperties" class="icon-caret-right"></i>&nbsp;Properties</strong>
```

When i click a button the icon-caret-right must be turned to icon-caret-down. i have written the code as follows:

```
 $('#iconProperties').removeClass('icon-caret-right').addClass('icon-caret-down');
```

When i use this code only the first row of the repeater is working. all other rows's icons are not changing. What is the mistake?

Comment: Are you using the same id on multiple elements?

Comment: same id in the sense??? i am using repeater.

Comment: As in `id="iconProperties"`. Are there multiple elements that have the exact same id in the generated HTML code that are sent to the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASP.net generates unique `ids` for html elements and only one element can have id `iconProperties` that you used in selector. You can use [Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) instead of id selector to get all the matching elements.

```
$('[id*=iconProperties]').removeClass('icon-caret-right').addClass('icon-caret-down');
```

Comment: ya. this will work. but anyone can plz explain the diff between [id*=iconProperties] and [id^=iconProperties] to understand better.

Comment: id* is for contains and id^ is for starts with

Comment: How to find the same element using document.getelementbyid instead of $ ?

Comment: This will give you an idea, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17452205/how-to-retrieve-all-td-where-the-id-begin-by-td-in-javascript/17452224#17452224

Answer (score 3):

If your `ids` have a similar name, you're probably after something like
    `$('[id^=iconProperties]').removeClass('icon-caret-right').addClass('icon-caret-down');`
Which will update all items beginning with id "iconProperties".

It might be worth noting that it is common practice to use unique `ids`.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$('#iconProperties').find('.icon-caret-right').replaceWith('.icon-caret-down');
```